# ngResource and Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: angularjs, rest, cors

I have set up a REST service using java and jetty with a CORS filter:

```
    response
        .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT");
```

I then try to fetch data from the rest service using AngularJS and ngResource:

```
$scope.nodes = $resource("http://localhost:8080/rest/forum/categories").query();
```

When I run the code I get the following message in the console log:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost/rest/forum/categories. 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin 'http://localhost:7000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

It seems that it has removed the :8080 from the URL in some way.

When I try to fetch the REST URL just using the browser things are fine. I have even checked the HTTP headers that are returned:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, POST, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT 
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:* 
Content-Type:application/json
```

Can someone tell my where I have gone wrong here?

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1243

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/18aO0bIlEm0

Comment: Thanks, akonsu. Could you please state your comment as an answer, so that I can accept it?